# How do I make glowing logo work in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, svg

I have a logo that I imported into Blender as an svg. I just want to make it glow. When I use Cycles I roughly get the result I want, but in EEVEE it just appears as a big glowing box.

Does anyone know how to make this work, or what the problem might be?

[image: cycles on top, Eve at the bottom]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, your issue can be resolved in the "Bloom" properties panel:

[image]

If you don't want ANY bloom/glare, you can simply toggle the "Bloom" off by clicking the checkbox.

If you want to "control" the bloom, so it's not extremely intense, adjusting the properties will solve your issue. Below I will briefly cover each Bloom property:

### Threshold:

This property adjusts the amount of emissive light that should be given bloom. For example, if the threshold is set to 5, an object with an emission  strength of 2 will not show ANY bloom, whereas an object with an emission strength of 50 will show a large amount of bloom

### Knee:

This property is not nearly as important as *Threshold*. Blender's definition of "Knee":

> Makes transition between under/over-threshold gradual

This is definition a little unclear, but basically, the knee value changes add bloom to objects that are close to the threshold. For example, if the threshold was set to 6, an object with an emission value of 1 would barely show any bloom, but if you turned up the Knee value, this object would show a little more bloom

### Radius:

This property is pretty self-explanatory but if it seems unclear, the radius property changes the amount, or size of the bloom:

[image]

### Color:

This property changes the colour of the bloom. Even if an object has an emission color of red, this color will overwrite it:

[image]

### Intensity:

This property is frequently mixed up with the *Radius* property, but they're actually quite different. The intensity property changes the "opacity" or amount of color/light within the Radius, whereas the Radius property changes the size of the surrounding light.

### Clamp:

Blender says:

> [Clamp is the maximum] intensity a bloom pixel can have.

---

Once again, I do not exactly understand your question, but if I hope this helped!

Comment: The bloom effect doesn't make it square shaped...

Comment: Oh, and now that I've read the answer completely: the _Color_ you can set in the _Bloom_ options is not overwriting the original color of an emissive material, it gets multiplied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do not show your material settings. I guess the *Emission* shader is plugged in the material's *Volume* output, not the *Surface* output. In *Eevee*, the volumetrics cannot be in the shape of the mesh, they are always filling the complete bounding box (or even more) of the object. So if you want to render with *Eevee*, plug the *Emission* shader into the *Surface* output.

[image: comparison]